# Certain GWMI queries no longer available?

Tags: performance, powershell, wmi, nic

In some of my PowerShell scripts I used the following Query to gather performance data for installed Network cards on the local computer:

```
$script:Tcpip_NI = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface -computername "localhost" -namespace "root\CIMV2"
```

For some reason I no longer get the NICs listed but the Error

```
Get-WmiObject : Die Anfrage ist ungültig. "select * from Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface"
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:20
+ $global:Tcpip_NI = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

keeps popping up now.

Since this has worked without any problem in the past months I am a bit dazzled why this query now yields no results anymore.

Anyone aware of any changes/hotfixes of Microsoft that could prevent PowerShell (v3.0 and older) to do this specific Performance Counter?

Tried to use the WMI Query Generator, ran it even as an Admin in order to have sufficient rights but even as an Admin I get the same error.

And is there an alternative way to gather performance data (such as actual transferred Bytes/s up/down etc.) for network cards using PowerShell?

All my searches lead back to this query type which no longer appears to work properly.

Comment: I can run this command on Windows 10 PS v5.1 and Server 2008 R2 PS v2 with out any issues. Whatever change occurred it is most likely not related to the PowerShell version. Is your WMI repository consistent?

Comment: Hello, I try to run this on a Win7 Enterprise installation. Most likely the WMI repository may no longer be consistent. - Any way to fix this without admin rights?

Comment: All methods that I know of require admin rights.